# Which processes do I need to kill in order to get a clean slate with Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bash, puma, guard

When I'm making rails applications I like to generate/scaffold quick examples to test an idea.

Naively, I've been expecting that if I end my `rails server` and `guard` sessions I should be able to fire up another rails app.

But I find that I get unexpected results. Sometimes the server won't start, sometimes a model/controller/scaffold won't generate, sometimes guard won't work.

I'm not sure why this is and end up spending around 1-5 minutes hacking around `pkill`ing until I'm back to a "clean" state where I can build a new app. It seems like `rails` and/or `guard`, `puma`, `webbrick`, and/or `spring` leave daemons going all over the place.

So far this is the processes I see that hang around, and how I kill them:

```
ps aux | grep ruby
ps aux | grep web
ps aux | grep puma
ps aux | grep spring

pkill -f ruby
pkill -f web
pkill -f puma
pkill -f spring
```

Is there a better approach to "reset my dev environment" so I can start developing another app?

Ideally what I'm looking for is a set of commands I can dump into a bash script named `reset_rails` that I can run and know with confidence that I'll be able to start my server, generate my scaffolds/models/controllers, and run my guard sessions.

Comment: What is the parent ID for them all ? Can you not just kill that assuming they all are started from the same place/program.

Comment: Can you link to or provide an example for how to do that?

Comment: Do they all have the same parent ID?

Comment: From `ps -f | grep spring` and `ps -f | grep puma` it looks like they do but `ps -f | grep ruby` it looks like no.

Comment: What is the process name of each of the parent ID's?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Skipping `spring` has been working well so far. Make it the default with by adding it to your `~/.railsrc` file with:

```
echo "--skip-spring" >> ~/.railsrc
```

or

```
echo "--skip-spring" > ~/.railsrc
```

If it doesn't already exist.